# Setting seconds to 0 is also adding 1 to minutes in Swift

Tags: swift, date, calendar, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm trying to set the seconds of a date object to 0 with the following:

```
if let date = value{
   var calendar = Calendar.current
    if let mdate = calendar.date(bySetting: .second, value: 0, of: date) {
        ...
}
}
```

However, this isn't just setting the seconds to 0, it's also adding 1 to the minutes, and I cannot understand why.

As you can see in this screenshot - I have a date object with a time value of "15:00:10", but this becomes "15:01:00" when I set the seconds to 0.

This does not seem intuitive. Do I need to subtract a minute each time? Can I be sure that this behavior is consistent?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is odd, and I'm not quite sure why it increments the minute.

You can get the result you are after by fetching the year/month/day/hour/minute component values from your date and then using those to create another date:

```
let value: Date? = Date()
if let date = value{
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    print(date.description(with: .current))
    
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date)
    
    if let mdate = calendar.date(from: components) {
        print(mdate.description(with: .current))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The misleadingly named `date(bySetting:value:of:)` is, [effectively](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685878), a simplified rendition of `nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:behavior:direction:)`. As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292915-date) say, if you need more control, you should use the latter.

E.g., go `.backward`.

```swift
if let mdate = calendar.nextDate(after: date, matching: DateComponents(second: 0), matchingPolicy: .nextTime, direction: .backward) {
    …
}
```

But as has been noted below, if seconds is already zero, this will get the prior date (!) with zero seconds.

---

Better might be to extract the components (sans seconds) and then build a date from that:

```swift
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.era, .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date)
if let mdate = calendar.date(from: components) {
    …
}
```

Comment: That works (voted) but man, the `nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:)` function is horribly named if it will return a date that is before the date passed to it. "Next date after this date that is actually *before* this date..."

Comment: If the current time is 15:05:00, your proposed solution returns 15:04:00, not 15:05:00.

Comment: Good catch, @HangarRash. I might suggest getting the components and then building the date from that.

Comment: Rob you said "I might suggest getting the components and then building the date from that.", That's how I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution if, and I assume this based on the image, the end goal is to generate a formatted string of the time with seconds set to zero then it can be directly solved with the date formatter by replacing `ss` in the format with `00`.

```
let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:00"
```